Setting umask for container running as jenkins
Because of restrictions on some of the tools we use, our Docker containers do not run as root. In the Dockerfile, the last thing I do is switch to the jenkins user. However, I need to set the umask to 0002. Putting a "RUN umask 0002" after "USER jenkins" doesn't work. How do I do this?

Umask values, like environment variables, are per-process, and since each RUN command creates a new container and a new shell then they won't be persisted in the image.  In this answer I show an entrypoint-based approach to it, but in a Jenkins context a better approach would probably be to specify the umask (and user ID!) as parameters in the Jenkinsfile when you're launching the container.

@DavidMaze "as parameters in the Jenkinsfile when you're launching the container." This doesn't make any sense to me. What "Jenkinsfile" are you talking about and how would parameters be specified?

You mentioned "Jenkins user" and that sounded like you were trying to use Jenkins's Docker integration.  That has a couple of ways to pass Docker arguments when you start a container, and you could add a -u option there.  Looking at the docker run reference, though, there doesn't actually seem to be a umask option, and I was probably thinking of --ulimit instead, which is different.

There is no way to specify a global umask setting when starting a Docker container. -u is used to specify a user. -ulimit is about ulimit, not umask.

You can set the umask for interactive shells by adding it to .bashrc.
FROM ubuntu:22.04

RUN useradd -m jenkins && \
    echo "umask 0002" >>/home/jenkins/.bashrc

USER jenkins
WORKDIR /home/jenkins

This will not be applied to subsequent RUN or CMD statements but it will work in an interactive shell.


Not what I need. I need it to be set to 0002 and STAY at 0002 for every process until the container exits.

Can you provide an example of what you have in mind? What processes are you planning on running? How are you going to run them (interactively or via CMD)?
